# How to use image URL from database and display in Razor page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having database table which include the urls of images..I tried to retrieve them and display in the cshtml page.But it doesn't display the images.But the Names of each photo is displayed.why is that??

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <img class="img-responsive" src="@item.Image" alt="" style="width:200px;height:200px" />
<h4 class="centered">@item.Name</h4>
}
```

in the Image column in the table, urls are stored as;

ex:
    ~/Images/Objects/fitem10.jpg

Comment: Is image available at that location? If you check generated HTML source what is the value of SRC tag coming out? Is relative path correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `src` property of the image:

```
<img src= "@Url.Content(item.Image)" alt="alternative text" />
```

`Url.Content()` resolves the relative path of the image into an absolute path for you.